# update a childnode in xml

Tags: asp.net, xml

I have a xml fil where I want to update one of the nodes.
I have no errors, and the code does something with the xml, the timestamp changes on the file.
But no update inside the document.

I have this xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<CGTemplateDATA>
  <title>Reden i Smedager</title>
  <text>Det er tidligt på sæsonen. Vi håber på bedre vejr og en mage til Clyde.</text>
  <reference>Læs mere om storkene på storkene.dk</reference>
</CGTemplateDATA>
```

and I use this script:

```
XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
//Get node
XmlNode nodeTitle = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("title");
//Create a new title element
XmlElement elem = doc.CreateElement("title");
elem.InnerText = txtTitle.Text;
//Replace the title element.
root.ReplaceChild(elem, nodeTitle);
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
Please edit your original question and provide the following:
(1) XML file sample. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic, and your code attempt trying to implement it. 
(3) Desired output based on the sample data in #1 above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better and easier to use LINQ to XML API. Its available in the .Net Framework since 2007.

The `.SetValue()` method does the job.

Here is a link where you can check how to retrieve text box value in ASP.NET:
[Retrieving value from Asp.Net TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13460215/retrieving-value-from-asp-net-textbox)

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    // XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(<fullyQualifiedPath>);
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(@"<CGTemplateDATA>
          <title>Reden i Smedager</title>
          <text>Det er tidligt på sæsonen. Vi håber på bedre vejr og en mage til Clyde.</text>
          <reference>Læs mere om storkene på storkene.dk</reference>
        </CGTemplateDATA>");

    xdoc.Element("CGTemplateDATA").Element("title").SetValue("New Title");
   // or even better option
   xdoc.Descendants("title").FirstOrDefault().SetValue("Even Better Title");
}
```

**Output**

```
<CGTemplateDATA>
  <title>New Title</title>
  <text>Det er tidligt på sæsonen. Vi håber på bedre vejr og en mage til Clyde.</text>
  <reference>Læs mere om storkene på storkene.dk</reference>
</CGTemplateDATA>
```

[image]

Comment: It does'nt change anything, except from the timestamp of the document, does not give me any errors either.

Comment: My answer is following a **minimal reproducible example** pattern. You run it as is, it is working, and producing a desired output.

Comment: I do'nt get it?
Should write the exact xml document in the parse og only the path to the xml document?

Comment: I added a commented line to the answer if you need to load XML file from the file system.  If your XML file is different from what you provided as a sample you need to edit your question and provide the real XML.

Comment: Thank you. Now I just need to get the right text inside the field.
I've updated my question...

Comment: I added a link to the answer where you can check how to retrieve textbox value.

Comment: I also thought so, I updated the code, but it does'nt put my string in.
Probably missing saomething?

Comment: I answered your question how to update XML element. I would suggest to close this question, and post a brand new question about asp.net